# MongoDB In-Memory as Redis Alternative?

Tags: mongodb, redis

Does anyone have experience with using MongoDB In-Memory as an alternative to Redis or the Cloud-Specific products (Elasticache, etc.)? I would love to keep my software cloud-agnostic while using a cloud-agnostic platform like MongoDB.  Any research or whitepapers you might have found would also be great help.  I have found [this article](https://scalegrid.io/blog/comparing-in-memory-databases-redis-vs-mongodb-percona-memory-engine/), but its focus is on a 3rd party product.

Comment: Redis is cloud agnostic

Comment: I understand, but I would rather use MongoDB for both the database and the caching.